# jsp ajax to spring controller-not hitting

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I am new to Ajax calling and MVC stuffs. I stuck with a problem my ajax call is not hitting controller.
My ajax code is as follows

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#SaveBtnId").click(function() {
        var seller = {};
        seller.firstName = $("#firstName").val();
        seller.gender = $("#gender").val();
        seller.companyName = $("#companyName").val();
        seller.tin_no = $("#tinNo").val();
        seller.lastName = $("#lastName").val();
        seller.dateOfBirth = $("#dateOfBirth").val();
        seller.epch_no = $("#EpchNo").val();
        //alert(JSON.stringify(seller));
        $.ajax({
            url : "../seller/addSeller",
            type : "POST",
            data : JSON.stringify(seller),
            contentType : "application/json",
            dataType : "json",
            success : function(data) {
                alert("success");
                alert(data);
            },
            error : function(error) {
                alert("failed");
                alert(error);
            }
        });
    });

});
```

And my controller code is as follows

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/addSeller" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody
ModelMap addSeller(@RequestBody SellerBO sellerBO, BindingResult bindingResult) {
    ModelMap modelMap = new ModelMap();
    try {
        log.info("controller");

         log.info("name " + sellerBO.getCompanyName());
         manageSellerServiceImpl.addSeller(sellerBO);

        log.info("added");
    } catch (Exception uExp) { 
        log.info("Error while adding seller", uExp);
    }
    return modelMap;

}
```

Problem is its not hitting controller, I don't know where i am going wrong.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Change the URL to something like this http://xyz/addSeller and in controller

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JSTL then change ajax URL to `<c:url value="/addSeller"/>`   otherwise change URL to `/addSeller` following application path
.